# A question about Schwarzschild manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Assume $(M,g)$ is Schwarzschild manifold, $A$ is the minimum area in the homology class of the boundary. How to prove that $A=$ the area of the horizon.

Comment: David, the underlying manifold $M$ of the Schwarzschild spacetime is $\mathbb{R}^2\times S^2$. It's an open manifold with no boundary. So what do you mean by that? Also, with no motivation, this comes off a bit like homework.

Comment: @Igor, I think the question is appropriate if it is edited to be the question in my answer (which I am pretty sure is the only reasonable question one could ask). I doubt it is homework (I might hazard a guess that it comes from reading Bray's thesis, where he asserts it is true, but leaves it to the reader, because it is not essential to his main goal).

Answer (score 5):

I'm interpreting your question in the only reasonable manner that I can think of:

> $M= \mathbb{R}^3\backslash \{0\}$ and $g_m = \left( 1 + \frac{m}{2r}\right)\delta$ is the "doubled" Schwarzschild. Of course it is easy to prove that $S_{m/2}(0)$ is a minimal surface. Is it true that $S_{m/2}(0)$ is actually area minimizing in its homology class?

This clearly is a stronger than the same question in "exterior" Schwarzschild, i.e. $M\backslash B_{m/2}(0)$ with the same metric there.

The answer is yes. I'll give a sketch because I'm short on time:

Let $w=1+\frac{m}{2r}$. $\Delta_\delta w = 0$ by computation (it has to hold if you look up the formula for conformal change of scalar curvature and know that Schwarzschild is scalar flat).

Then, if $\Sigma$ is a "competitor" which is homologous to $S_{m/2}$, an appropriate Green's theorem shows that
$$
\int_{S_{m/2}} D_\nu w = \int_\Sigma D_\nu w
$$
These integrals are all with respect to the $\delta$-quantities. Here is where I will skip the details. Multiply by some constant $C$ (which you should explicitly determine) so that the LHS becomes $area(S_{m/2},g_m)$. That is
$$
area(S_{m/2}(0),g_m) = C\int_{S_{m/2}} D_\nu w = C\int_\Sigma D_\nu w
$$
Now, I'll leave it up to you to check that $CD_\nu w$ is bounded from above by $w^4$ (you just need to compute the various quantities). Thus, we've shown that
$$
area(S_{m/2}(0),g_m) \leq \int_\Sigma w^4 = area(\Sigma,g_m).
$$
You may further check that equality implies that $\Sigma = S_{m/2}(0)$.

This is a classic example of a "calibration" argument.

I'll remark that Hugh Bray, in his [thesis](http://arxiv.org/abs/0902.3241) gave a beautiful argument to show that the other centered spheres are isoperimetric. These ideas have had a good deal of influence in related works, e.g. Eichmair--Metzger [proved](http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.2999) a quantitative isoperimetric inequality in Schwarzschild and used this to study large isoperimetric surfaces in initial data which is $C^0$-asymptotic to Schwarzschild. Also, Brendle--Eichmair used this, along with other results to [study](http://arxiv.org/abs/1208.3988) isoperimetric surfaces in the "doubled" Schwarzschild, as I defined above.